# О собственной модели авторизации

Tags: django

Всем, привет! Запутался в собственной модели авторизации.

1) Создаю backend:

cat backends.py

```
 from django.conf import settings
 from django.contrib.auth.models import User, check_password

 class authUTM5Backend(object):
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        if username is not None:
            return username
        else:
            return None
```

2) Прописываю в settings.py

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'authutm5.backends.authUTM5Backend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',)
```

3) Описываю саму авторизацию:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth import logout

def login_view(request):
   if request.user.is_authenticated():
       return redirect(reverse('search'))
   if request.method == 'POST':
       username = request.POST['username']
       password = request.POST['password']
       user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)
       if user is not None:
           login(request, user)
       else:
           return redirect(reverse('login'))
   return auth_views.login(request, 'accounts/login.html')
```

В итоге получаю ошибку:

```
'unicode' object has no attribute 'backend'
```

Answer (score 2):

Бекэнд должен возвращать экземпляр объекта `django.contrib.auth.models.User`, а не `username`:

```
class authUTM5Backend(object):
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        if username is not None:
            try:
                user = User.objects.get(username=username)

                if ... # тут проверка пароля
                    return user
                else:
                    return None
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                return None
        else:
            return None
```

P.S. также рекомендую в бекэнд включать метод:

```
def get_user(self, user_id):
    try:
        return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return None
```

в общем всё равно придётся :)

Comment: User.objects.get() делает select из своих таблиц(auth_user), а мне нужно сделать select из собственной таблицы проверку.

Comment: Ок, разрешаю Вам сделать из своей :) Просто Ваш код похож на нативный, я нативный и привёл как пример. В любом случае придётся либо сопоставить свою таблицу юзеров с нативной (сопоставить/создать там для них записи) и всё равно возвращать их, либо использовать собственный класс юзера (начиная с 1.5) и возвращать уже его.